# Showing icon next to text using CSS with ::before selector - text not aligning properly

Tags: html, css

Here is a minimal version of my code:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        div.tip {
            padding: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            border: 2px solid transparent;
            border-radius: 7px;
            color: #155724;
            background-color: #d4edda;
            border-color: #c3e6cb;
            display: flex;
            width: 700px;
            text-align: justify;
            min-height: 30px;
        }

        .tip::before {
            content: "";
            background-image: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/702/702797.svg");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 30px;
            width: 30px;
            background-position-y: center;
            padding-right: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="tip">
        <span><b>Tip</b>: Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="tip">
        <span><b>Tip</b>: Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="tip">
        <span><b>Tip</b>: Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="tip">
        <span><b>Tip</b>: Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</span>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you run the snippet you will see that the text aligns at different places horizontally depending on how many lines are in the text. How can I fix this so that the text always aligns at the same position next to the icon? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using `flex`

Comment: @Asutosh he's using flex

Comment: flex-shrink:0 to the pseudo element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert `flex: none` in `.tip::before`

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        div.tip {
            padding: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            border: 2px solid transparent;
            border-radius: 7px;
            color: #155724;
            background-color: #d4edda;
            border-color: #c3e6cb;
            display: flex;
            width: 700px;
            text-align: justify;
            align-items: center;
            position: relative;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .tip::before {
            content: "";
            background-image: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/702/702797.svg");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 30px;
            width: 30px;
            min-height: 35px;
            background-position-y: center;
            padding-right: 30px;
            flex: none;
        }
        .tip hr {
            width: 30px;
            height: 0;
            transform: rotate(90deg);
            position: absolute;
            margin: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 1px solid black;
            left: 35px;
        } 
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="tip">
        <hr>
        <span><b>Tip</b>: Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="tip">
        <hr>
        <span><b>Tip</b>: Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="tip">
        <hr>
        <span><b>Tip</b>: Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="tip">
        <hr>
        <span><b>Tip</b>: Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah. Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</span>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Done! Also, do you have any idea how I can center the text vertically when there is only one line? I tried to look it up, but did not find anything useful.

Comment: (after adding `min-height: 30px;`)

Comment: I want to suggest improving your code a little. You have another problem. here it is in the screenshot - https://ibb.co/6bzKZwG. the height of your icon adjusts to the height of the text - and that's not correct. in order to eliminate do the following: in `.tip :: before` add `min-height: 35px`, and in `div.tip` add `align-items: center;`

Comment: I have updated the answer. Your text is now vertically centered and the icon does not fade away with small text. Check, please.

Comment: Works perfectly and much improved, thanks again! :) Last question, how do I add a vertical separator line between the icon and the text?

Comment: you can use the hr tag. i updated answer

Comment: Sorry, now I am facing another problem that I don't know how to fix... I'm trying to align the tip box to the center using `margin: auto`, but this makes the line appear in a completely different place. How can I center the boxes while keeping the line in the correct place?

Comment: I'll answer later. wait please

Comment: check answer pls

Comment: I added `position: relative` and in `div.tip` and `left: 35px` in `.tip hr`

Comment: Great! You're a lifesaver :)

Comment: Nice to hear that. Thank you, bro :))